# Joomla 3.6 Module Show Title not working

Tags: module

I have 2 sites, one where this is working and one where it is not
[this site the titles work](http://customsigncenter.com/holiday-banners)
[this one they don't](http://4signs.com/banners/holiday)
all the settings are the same and the SHOW button is green

can I get a hint? :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the template you are using usually - does this template have headers in place for those module positions? I know some templates don't include this by default.

Comment: I have only ever used the default template that was here when I got here last august 2016. I'd share it but I'm unable to add images here

Comment: both sites are set up the same, as far as I can tell  Customsigncenter.com has the titles showing correctly: http://customsigncenter.com/business-banners  and 4signs.com does not http://4signs.com/banners/business  I don't do a lot of coding, only working in Joomla 3.6